# 0 Unable to open YAML file in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, yaml

## [Jmeter Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW0ef.png)

Unable to open YAML file in JMeter throws "only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not m (position: START_DOCUMENT seen \r\nm... @2:2) " error in a popup. Can anyone know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter [.jmx test scripts](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) are [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) files, not YAML.

If you got the YAML file from [BlazeMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium) and looking for a way of converting it into a JMeter script you will need [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool for this.

If you run Taurus as:

```
bzt Recording_1.yaml -gui
```

it will bring up JMeter GUI and you will be able to see your script, make changes, run, etc.